# Are there any good JQuery twitter widgets which loop over tweets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I'm wondering if there are any JQuery widgets out there that provide the feature for looping over loaded tweets? For example in the official widget http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile there is an option to 'loop results' and I was wondering if there were any 3rd Party widgets which did the same?

Ideally I would like to apply this feature to the code I already have.

I found this excellent twitter plugin and it was really easy to customize the css. I only realized after that my site looks pretty static so I thought it might be a good idea to loop over my tweets to make it more dynamic, although I have no idea how to do this!

I downloaded the code from here: http://demo.marcofolio.net/unlimited_scroll/

A copy of the code is here as well: http://pastebin.com/e2kHtSpt

Thanks for any help in advance, I really appreciate it!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I loop over my tweets by editing JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556974/can-i-loop-over-my-tweets-by-editing-jquery)  You don't need to post multiple questions asking the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike Alsup, of jQuery Core Team has written a wonderful twitter search  plugin which loops the results.
( [Demo here](http://jquery.malsup.com/twitter/) )