# How do I change the number of loaded tweets in my JQuery widget?

Tags: jquery, twitter

After [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557502/are-there-any-good-jquery-twitter-widgets-which-loop-over-tweets) where I could find a good JQuery widget I got directed [to here](http://jquery.malsup.com/twitter/).

It's the best widget I've found so far and very customizable, **the only problem is I can't find if I can load more than 4 tweets into the feed?** I've been looking through the code but I can't seem to find where it's defined.

- [A copy of the code](http://pastebin.com/WFp5UcUi).
- [A copy of the page](http://pastebin.com/P3yt5Bwq) I'm working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four results you are seeing aren't actually a limitation of the plugin, but a limitation of the twitter search function. I suffer the same problem on [my website](http://www.whoiskarl.com/) too. Basically, the twitter search facility limits itself to only "recent" tweets.

If you tweet a lot, this plugin will show you a lot of tweets, if you don't tweet a lot, you might only see one or two, or maybe none at all if you haven't tweeted for a long time.

To prove this, if you go to http://search.twitter.com/ and enter your username in the search box, only the same 4 tweets will be returned.

If you need more control over what you want to see, you might need to consider looking into the [Twitter API](http://dev.twitter.com/) instead.