# I would like to create a twitter widget using JQuery - where should I start?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter

After asking the following questions:

Question 1: [Are there any good JQuery twitter widgets which loop over tweets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557502/are-there-any-good-jquery-twitter-widgets-which-loop-over-tweets)

Question 2: [How do I change the number of loaded tweets in my JQuery widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575546/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-loaded-tweets-in-my-jquery-widget)

I found that there are no twitter widgets out there that really perform what I want to do. So I have come to the conclusion that I should write my own to achieve what I want.

I'm fairly new to JQuery, I've only really ever edited existing code so are there any good tutorials out there?

Also I'm not 100% sure if what I want to achieve is possible using just JQuery and CSS so I'm going to write what I would like the widget to do.

Functionality:

Load tweets from a specific user

Loop over loaded tweet results

Interface:

Tweets fade in and fade out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise you to start at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring. Apologies for such a generic answer but the guidelines really do help and sort of say it all really.

Good luck!

Comment: To further add to this, I found this tutorial is a great start for writing a jQuery plugin: http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html